# Flutter Isolate: Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter beginner here. I wanted to create an isolate. Do some task while keeping the isolate alive and then kill the isolate when I want to. But re-spawning the isolate is producing the following error:

```
E/flutter (30176): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
E/flutter (30176): #0      _StreamController._subscribe (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:676:7)
E/flutter (30176): #1      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:827:19)
E/flutter (30176): #2      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:471:9)
E/flutter (30176): #3      _ReceivePortImpl.listen (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:92:31)
E/flutter (30176): #4      _IsolateExampleWidgetState._spawnIsolate (package:niyog/home/IsolateScreen.dart:27:40)
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IsolateExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IsolateExampleWidgetState createState() => _IsolateExampleWidgetState();
}

class _IsolateExampleWidgetState extends State<IsolateExampleWidget> {
  Isolate? _isolate;
  late ReceivePort _receivePort;
  late SendPort _sendPort;

  late StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _receivePort = ReceivePort();
  }

  void _spawnIsolate() async {
    _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEntryPoint, _receivePort.sendPort);
    print("isolate spawning");

    _streamSubscription = _receivePort.listen((message) {
      if (message is SendPort) {
        _sendPort = message;
      } else {
        print(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void _sendToIsolate() {
    _sendPort.send('hello from main thread');
  }

  void _killIsolate() {
    _isolate?.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
    _streamSubscription.cancel();
    _receivePort.close();
    print("killed");
  }

  static void _isolateEntryPoint(SendPort sendPort) {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      final String? text = message as String?;
      final String uppercaseText = text?.toUpperCase() ?? '';
      sendPort.send(uppercaseText);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _killIsolate();
    _receivePort.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _spawnIsolate,
          child: Text('Spawn Isolate'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _sendToIsolate,
          child: Text('Send to Isolate'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _killIsolate,
          child: Text('Kill Isolate'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: The issue is coming when you are trying to reassign `_streamSubscription`  ig

Comment: even if i remove the variable `_streamSubscription`, it still produces the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to listen to the _receivePort multiple times when you spawn the isolate again. To fix this, you can create a new ReceivePort and corresponding StreamSubscription when you spawn the isolate, and close the previous ReceivePort when you kill the isolate.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IsolateExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IsolateExampleWidgetState createState() => _IsolateExampleWidgetState();
}

class _IsolateExampleWidgetState extends State<IsolateExampleWidget> {
  Isolate? _isolate;
  late ReceivePort _receivePort;
  late SendPort _sendPort;

  StreamSubscription? _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _receivePort = ReceivePort();
  }

  void _spawnIsolate() async {
    // Cancel the previous StreamSubscription if it exists
    if (_streamSubscription != null) {
      await _streamSubscription.cancel();
    }

    // Close the previous ReceivePort if it exists
    if (_receivePort != null) {
      _receivePort.close();
    }

    // Create a new ReceivePort
    _receivePort = ReceivePort();

    _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEntryPoint, _receivePort.sendPort);
    print("isolate spawning");

    _streamSubscription = _receivePort.listen((message) {
      if (message is SendPort) {
        _sendPort = message;
      } else {
        print(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void _sendToIsolate() {
    _sendPort.send('hello from main thread');
  }

  void _killIsolate() {
    _isolate?.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
    _streamSubscription?.cancel();
    _receivePort.close();
    print("killed");
  }

  static void _isolateEntryPoint(SendPort sendPort) {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      final String? text = message as String?;
      final String uppercaseText = text?.toUpperCase() ?? '';
      sendPort.send(uppercaseText);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _killIsolate();
    _receivePort.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _spawnIsolate,
          child: Text('Spawn Isolate'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _sendToIsolate,
          child: Text('Send to Isolate'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _killIsolate,
          child: Text('Kill Isolate'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i got the idea although the answer has a slight mistake. Removing the 'late' keyword from StreamSubscription and changing the `_streamSubscription.cancel()` to `_streamSubscription?.cancel()` is working just as expected. It would be nice if you update the answer as I am accepting this one. many thanks

Comment: I'm glade it helped. cheers